# Imported GeoTIFF file returns only NAN values

Tags: import, gis, tiff, gdal

I have been trying to import a GEOTIFF file that shows irradiance data. I am able to plot (see [Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELgks.png) here) the file so I am sure the file has data; however; the raster array contains only nan values. Is there any way to resolve this? I am quite new to python so perhaps I've missed something obvious, any help would be appreciated  :)

This is the code I'm using:

```
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import gc
gc.enable()

#import 
ds = gdal.Open('DNI_Spain.tif')
gt = ds.GetGeoTransform()
proj = ds.GetProjection()

band = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
array = band.ReadAsArray()
max_value = np.max(array)
min_value = np.min(array)
median_value = np.median(array)


plt.figure()
plt.imshow(array)
```

Comment: Are you basing your belief about the raster values based on `max_value`, `min value` and `median_value`? If so, you should be using
`np.nanmax`
`np.nanmin` and `np.nanmedian`.

Comment: Hi @RobertDavy, no I was looking through the values in the array variable. Did I perhaps use the wrong function to read the array as well?

Comment: Just a follow up, I used the np.nanmax functions etc, and got values. Is there a way to read the array/raster in the same manner to see all the values?

Comment: It turns out the values were there, the array was just so large that I didn't see any without really scrolling through the entire array. Thank you for the help though !